# How to auto calculate the price value in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to calculate the price according to room and per day for booking in a hotel. Suppose a person books 2 room of price 1000 each for 2 days. Therefore the total price will be 2000*2 = 4000. I done this using Javascript but while changing the input values I need to again refresh the page. I need to do this like auto-calculate in any change of the text values. 
Already implemented code is -

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select.rooms").change(function () {
            var selectedrooms = $(".rooms option:selected").val();
            $("#tr").val("" + selectedrooms);

            var tprice = $("#price").val() * selectedrooms;

            $("#tprice").val("" + tprice);
            $("#checkout-date").change(function () {
                var selectedoutdate = $("#checkout-date").val();
                var selectedindate = $("#checkin-date").val();

            });


        });
        ///var txtto = document.getElementById("#txtTo");

        if ($("#txtFrom").val() != "" && $("#txtTo").val() != "") {

            var From_date = new Date($("#txtFrom").val());
            var To_date = new Date($("#txtTo").val());
            var diff_date = To_date - From_date;

            //var years = Math.floor(diff_date / 31536000000);
            //var months = Math.floor((diff_date % 31536000000) / 2628000000);
            var days = Math.floor(((diff_date % 31536000000) % 2628000000) / 86400000);

            $("#days").html(days);
            //alert( years+" year(s) "+months+" month(s) "+days+" and day(s)");

            var ttp = days * $("#tprice").val();
            //alert("days: " + days + "price: " + $("#tprice").val() + "ttp: " + ttp);
            //$("#priceDetails").html(selectedrooms + " and " + days + " day(s): " + ttp);

            $("#priceDetails").html(days + " day(s) and " + $(".rooms option:selected").val() + " Room(s): ");
            $("#prc").html(ttp);
        }
        else {
            //alert("Please select dates");
            $("#priceDetails").html("0.0");
            return false;
        }

    });

</script>
```

and my input boxes (HTML) code is -

```
<form class="" id="form-booking" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Check-In</label>
                            <input type="text" required="true" placeholder="Check-In" id="txtFrom" title="Add your Check In date" class="checkin form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Check-Out</label>
                            <input type="text" required="true" id="txtTo" placeholder="Check-out" title="Type in your Check out date" class="checkout form-control" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Rooms</label>
                            <select id="rooms" required="required" style="font-size:small" class="rooms form-control dropdown">
                                <option disabled="disabled">Select...</option>
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                                <option>5+</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div id="divmsg" class="" style="display:block">
                                <p id="pmsg" class="text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
```

Any suggestions? how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to place your code inside input blur event in order to auto calculate final price

https://api.jquery.com/blur/